# QUnit fails with grunt, passes in the browser

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gruntjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

In the script I'm developing, I check to see if a variable is `instanceof HTMLAudioElement`. When I run QUnit via a grunt task, it fails with

```
>> Message: Died on test #1     at file:///path/test/lib/qunit.js:425
>>     at file:///path/test/all.js:24: Can't find variable: HTMLAudioElement
>> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLAudioElement
```

`all.js` doesn't actually reference `HTMLAudioElement` itself, it just calls some code in my main script that would use it.

All the tests pass when I open `all.html` in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari.

Is this expected behavior? Is it using some sort of browser emulation that doesn't have that constructor? Does this mean that my code will fail in some browser, or is this just misconfiguration that doesn't tell me anything useful? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry friend, but according to [their website](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Supported-Web-Standards), PhantomJS does not support the HTML5 `audio` or `video` elements, thus the `HTMLAudioElement` constructor will not exist.

You can get your tests to pass by having a condition around that code checking for compatibility with unsupported browsers, maybe using something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?

Comment: Thank you. This is my first go with QUnit on one of my own projects, so I had no idea where to begin.